# How to use getters and setters in v-model for class based component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm a newbie to vuejs and i'm from angular background.  I'm trying to bind my setter/getter in v-model for an input. But that is not working as I'm intending it to. But when I tried to bind it to variable directly, then it's working fine.

**Following is my code:**

### My Component TS file:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    components: {}
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    private _username: string = '';
    private _password: string = '';


    get username(): string {
        return this._username;
    }

    set username(value: string) {
        this._username = value;
    }

    get password(): string {
        return this._password;
    }

    set password(value: string) {
        this._password = value;
    }

    public login() {
        console.log(this.username, this.password);
    }
}
```

### MyComponent Vue file:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
        <v-text-field
                v-model="username"
                label="Username"
                required>
        </v-text-field>
        <v-text-field
                v-model="password"
                :type="'password'"
                label="Password"
                required>
        </v-text-field>
        <v-btn large type="submit">Login</v-btn>
        <v-btn large>Reset</v-btn>
    </form>
</template>
```

I was expecting username and password value typed into the respective fields to be displayed in the console. But instead all I get is `undefined undefined` (Even though I have initialized the variable to empty string). I did go through the documentation, but it was not of much help since i'm using typescript with vue-class-component. Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Very interesting, even the getter is not working. I'll try tomorrow when i have my computer with me if not yet answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)

> Properties that start with _ or $ will not be proxied on the Vue
> instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and
> API methods. You will have to access them as vm.$data._property.

Simply don't use the _ prefix to solve the problem.

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    components: {}
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    private xusername: string = '';
    private xpassword: string = '';


    get username(): string {
        return this.xusername;
    }

    set username(value: string) {
        this.xusername = value;
    }

    get password(): string {
        return this.xpassword;
    }

    set password(value: string) {
        this.xpassword = value;
    }

    public login() {
        console.log(this.username, this.password);
    }
}
```